# Android: Sharing Data and Receiving text from 3rd party app. Why doesn't my app receive new text?

Tags: android, android-intent, intentfilter

**Summary**

I am attempting to get data sent from the user via the Share menu.  In this case, I'll use the basic Android web browser to select text and then share it to my app.

**Problem**

The first time the user shares the text my app gets the text as expected and displays it via *Log.d()* -- see the *handleSendText()* method in the code below.

However, each time thereafter even though the user has selected new text in the web browser and shared it with my app, I still get the original text the user selected (previous value).

**Question**

How do you reset the Intent -- or whatever it is  -- so that I can obtain the new text the user has selected after the first time?

**Details**

My application has a MainActivity and I've followed the Google docs at :
http://developer.android.com/training/sharing/receive.html

With code like the following in my MainActivity

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Intent intent = getIntent();
    String action = intent.getAction();
    String type = intent.getType();

    if (Intent.ACTION_SEND.equals(action) && type != null) {
        if ("text/plain".equals(type)) {
            handleSendText(intent, "onCreate"); // Handle text being sent
        }
    }
}

@Override
public void onResume(){
    super.onResume();
    Intent intent = getIntent();
    String action = intent.getAction();
    String type = intent.getType();

    if (Intent.ACTION_SEND.equals(action) && type != null) {
        if ("text/plain".equals(type)) {
            handleSendText(intent, "onResume"); // Handle text being sent
        }
    }

}

void handleSendText(Intent intent, String callingMethodName) {
    String sharedText = intent.getStringExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT);
    if (sharedText != null) {
    Log.d("MainActivity", "sharedText : " + sharedText + " called from : " + callingMethodName);
    }
}
```

}

My AndroidManifest section for the activity has the filter added like:

```
<activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <data android:mimeType="text/plain" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
```

**Walk-Thru With Screens and Log**

**NOTE:** Please notice that I've implemented the onResume() in my app also to insure that I don't only get the Intent when onCreate() is called (only one time when the app is started).

**Start up browser and grab the text "hurricane".**

[image: grab text hurricane]

**Choose the app to share with (our test app).**

[image: share with GrabText app]

**View the log and notice that onCreate() and onResume() are called and value is 'hurricane'**

[image: view log see values]

**Go back to browser again to share more text...**

[image: back to browser]

**Select a new word, Atlantic, to share.**

[image: select new word: atlantic]

**Extra note**: When we click that Share link this time the Android MenuChooser doesn't display, instead, it automatically opens GrabText again.  I found that behavior somewhat odd.

Notice that the Intent text still has the value of hurricane.  You can see that there are now two new entries in the logcat.

[image: intent text is still hurricane]

**Attempted Workaround Solutions**

I have found that I can destroy the app entirely by overriding *onPause()* and calling *finish()* on my Activity (thus closing the entire app) and that seems to work, but isn't there some other way to reset that Intent or the associated text or something?

Do you know of any other way to insure that the new data is retrieved?
I appreciate any help.

**UPDATE**
**Note**:I'm updating because there's not a great way to show additional code tried, however, I wouldn't have know to try this without input from other SO User, **CommonsWare**.

The first answer I received was that I should add an *@Override onNewIntent()* so I added the following code to my MainActivity:

```
 @Override
    protected void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {
        super.onNewIntent(intent);
        Log.d("MainActivity", "onNewIntent()...");
        String action = intent.getAction();
        String type = intent.getType();
        if (Intent.ACTION_SEND.equals(action) && type != null) {
            if ("text/plain".equals(type)) {
                handleSendText(intent, "onNewIntent"); // Handle text being sent
            }
        }

    }
```

Upon adding that code and running and attempting the copy and then second copy of the new word, I still saw the following in logcat:

[image: still doesn't capture new word]

It doesn't even look as if the *onNewItent()* method is even called.

**EDIT 2**

I altered the emulator Settings...Developer Options... and turned off the "Don't keep activities" setting.  It was previously turned on (checked).
[image: don't keep activities]

After that, I ran the app which contains the *onNewIntent()* override but now it shows just the one *onCreate()* gone (which makes sense because the activity is still loaded) but still does not show the onNewIntent() call.
In this sample, I captured the word "remnants".

[image: another attempted capture]

**Edit 3**

I built the app and created an APK and deployed it to my Samsung Galaxy Core Prime and I ended up with the same results.  *onNewIntent()* is **never** called.

I just looked up onNewIntent in Google docs and it states:

> **onNewIntent(Intent intent)** This is **called for activities that set
>   launchMode to "singleTop"** in their package, or if a client used the
>   FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP flag when calling startActivity(Intent).

I haven't set singleTop so I will try it now. Hmm....

**EDIT 4**

I have now tried the singleTop variation.  I was previously testing on API 15 (v4.0.4)on an emulator so I switched to API 21 (v5.0) to see if there'd be any different.

Here's what the addition of singleTop did to my AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<activity android:name=".MainActivity" android:launchMode="singleTop">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        <data android:mimeType="text/plain" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

Notice I also collapsed the two intent-filter nodes into the one.

**Selected Text Did Change**

On Android API Level 21 the Intent text was now coming in different each time I selected text in the browser.

**onNewIntent Is Never Called**

However, onNewIntent is NEVER called.  I don't ever see it fire.

**Share Menu Displayed Every Time**

Also, now (on API 21) I see the Share menu every time I select text.
However, I also see an interesting thing when I switch to the browser.  You can see multiple copies of the Activity in the list.  What?!

[image: multiple copies of grabtext]

Notice also that I implemented the MainActivity as a ListView (scrollable) so I could see the entries even without logcat (for running on real device). That made something else apparent: that the ListView was being updated on each newly shown Activity. But really, it should be the original Activity being appended to.

**Creates Numerous GrabText Activities**
Yes, now it creates a new GrabText Activity window each time I select text.  I thought maybe that was because I had the singleTop set so I removed it but they still appear even after removing singleTop on API LEVEL 21.

Now that I saw it work -- provide different text each time on API 21 I decided to switch back to API Level 15 emulator and try it.

I will report back after I try some things back on API Level 15 again.

**API Level 15 : Test Again**

I started my other emulator running API Level 15 again and ran the app and even with singleTop set the value is never updated.

You can see this in the logcat and on the updated ListView:

[image: logcat onResume]

[image: append to ListView via api15]

You can also see that the code acts completely different, though I've not changed anything since it appends to the ListView of the one running Activity on api level 15.

I've written a book on this terribly documented thing.  I hope this helps someone and that a Google Android dev sees this and explains it.

Comment: I tried your code without the `onNewIntent()` method and it's working completely fine on my side.  am testing it on an emulator with Android Marshmallow.

Comment: @PrerakSola Thanks for trying it out.  I am running on an emulator and was going to build for my physical device to test it too.  I was wondering if it was possible that it is the emulator (which is running Android 4.0.4).

Comment: @PrerakSola you are right. It "works" on API Level 21 (v5.0) also.  However, it never seems to work on API Level 15 (v4.0.4) the original API i was testing it on. My galaxy core is running 4.4 and it doesn't seem to work there either.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

There is only one answer that actually works, but it could cause other problems.

You just have to decide to call finish() whenever the Activity goes into onPause().

Here's the exact code I implemented which works on all API LEVELS.

```
@Override
    public void onPause(){
        super.onPause();
        finish();
    }
```

**Destroy the Activity**

When you add that code then every time you switch back to the app you are sharing from (the web browser in our case) then the onPause will fire on your MainActivity and the finish() method will set the Activity for destruction.

**Share Menu Displayed Every Time After This**

With this solution every time you select text from your sharing app (web browser) then the Share menu will be displayed and will display GrabText as one of the choices (instead of automatically forcing GrabText to the front again).

**Shared Text Is Always the New Text**

Since the MainActivity is completely destroyed it then has to be completely loaded (onCreate()) again and so it receives the new Intent text which was sent.

**Not A Great Workaround**

This isn't a great workaround however, because I believe dialog boxes in your app would also create onPause() to be called and your Activity would be destroyed.  Obviously destroying your Activity onPause() just isn't great either because you are beginning to manage "memory" in a way that really should be left to the OS.  However, in this case it seems to be the only way around the issue.

Answer (score -1):

If your activity already exists, it will be called with `onNewIntent()` instead of `onCreate()`. `onNewIntent()` will be passed the `Intent` that you need to use for your message.

Comment: I will try this right now.  If that is the simple answer, it will be fantastic!! I could not find that documented anywhere.

Comment: commonsware, I implemented the override but I don't ever see the onNewIntent() is even being called.  Maybe I'm doing something wrong?  I added the attempted code to my edited question so you can see.  Thanks.

Comment: @daylight: Well, the logs suggest that a new instance of your activity is being created. You might log `onDestroy()` calls to see if the old instance is going away, plus log something like the `hashCode()` of the activities in these log statements so you can confirm what activity instance(s) you are dealing with. Your "`finish()` clears it up" suggested that the old instance was being reused, but then `onNewIntent()` should be getting called.

Comment: I'll work through a few more things with your suggestions in mind and see what I can get to.  However, as I'm thinking about it, it is still very odd that if GrabText is closing (as seems to be indicated by the second call to onCreate() it is very odd that it still has the old value of "hurricane". Either way, it all seems messed up.  I appreciate your input very much.

Answer (score -1):

Try changing the [android:launchMode](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#lmode) of your activity in the manifest.xml to
**singleTop**

this way if the activity is already launched, new intents will be received in **onNewIntent**() method

Comment: Well, I'd have to research that further to determine if using a BroadCastReceiver is the correct way to share simple text like this.  Also, the feature I'm attempt to implement is the ActivityChooser menu that appears at the top (Share) of android when user selects text.  Would the BroadCastReceiver register itself that way and show up as a item in the Share menu?  Also, if you google "share data between apps" the first link returned is Google's official document on how to do this which is exactly what I'm following : http://developer.android.com/training/sharing/index.html.

Comment: You're right, the your implementation is the best for showing the activity in the intent chooser, please check my updated answer

Comment: Yes, in my Edit 3 notes i menionted that I'm trying that now.  It looks like it does solve the problem that the text is changed each time. However, it does not look likeonNewIntent() is ever called. Originally I was testing on API 15 (4.0.4) now I'm testing on API 21 just to see how it all works. Thanks for your input.